# Manage state and submission of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Very new to React. I'm using (the equivalent of) checkboxes as a way for a user to select/deselect their skills and I'm wondering what's the best way to handle the state?

Essentially the flow is like this:

1. Initial values are pulled from the database. The API will provide a
   list of skills (by name) and all of those skills are the ones that should
   start out as checked whilst the others are unchecked
2. The user can freely check/uncheck boxes and if they click the cancel button the states will return to the initial values
3. If the user presses the submit button, the state will be changed and the form submitted with the value

I've done the same thing on another page but that was text fields and there was only 5 of them so I just stored their values in the state individually. Since I have over 30 checkboxes that seems like it'd be very messy. Is there a good way to condense this sort of thing and also how would I map this?

They are checked/unchecked as indicated by their property "checked: (true/false)"

This is the code at the moment (I removed most of the select items so it wasn't a massive list):

```
import * as React from "react";

import { Form, Card, Grid } from "tabler-react";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

class Skills extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     showSaveButton: false,
     showCancelButton: false,
    };
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        showSaveButton: true,
        showCancelButton: true,
      });

      if(event.target.checked){
        console.log(event.target.checked)
      } else {
        console.log("not checked")
      }
  }

  cancelChanges = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        showSaveButton: false,
        showCancelButton: false,
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card" name="skills">
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>Top skills</Card.Title>
          <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Col offset={1} md={10}>
              <Form.Group name="softskills" label="Soft Skills">
                <Form.SelectGroup canSelectMultiple pills onChange={this.onChange}>
                  <Form.SelectGroupItem
                    label="Communication"
                    name="communication"
                    value="Communication"
                  />
                  <Form.SelectGroupItem
                    label="Teamwork"
                    name="teamwork"
                    value="Teamwork"
                  />
             </Form.SelectGroup>
              </Form.Group>
            </Grid.Col>
          </Grid.Row>
          <Button content='Cancel changes' floated='left' color='red' basic hidden={this.state.showCancelButton ? '' : 'hidden'} onClick={this.cancelChanges}/>
          <Button content='Save changes' floated='right' color='green' basic hidden={this.state.showSaveButton ? '' : 'hidden'}/>
        </Card.Body>
 </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Skills;
```

Answer (score 0):

With plain react (without redux and hooks) you can maintain a state object of type map for checked items like this

```
selectedItems: new Map(),
```

then in `onChange` event update selctedItems.

```
onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        showSaveButton: true,
        showCancelButton: true,
      });

      this.setState(prevState => ({ 
           selectedItems: prevState.selectedItems.set(event.target.name, event.target.checked),
           showSaveButton: true,
           showCancelButton: true 
      }));
     
}
```

[React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs) has explained this with a nice example on how to maintain state of multiple inputs (here checkboxes).

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
 }
```